# Unusual variable type mismatches

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, number-literal

If I run the command:

```
Resize-VHD -ComputerName $VMhost -Path "D:\VMs\$VMname\Virtual Hard Disks\$vmname.vhdx" -SizeBytes 70GB
```

Powershell is clever enough to understand what 70GB is, accept the arguement and will resize the drive,

However, if I do :

```
$drivesize = "70GB"

Resize-VHD -ComputerName $VMhost -Path "D:\VMs\$VMname\Virtual Hard Disks\$vmname.vhdx" -SizeBytes $drivesize
```

I get the following error:

```
Resize-VHD : Cannot bind parameter 'SizeBytes'. Cannot convert value "70GB" to type "System.UInt64". Error: "Input string was 
not in a correct format."
At line:22 char:100
+ ... D:\VMs\$VMname\Virtual Hard Disks\$vmname.vhdx" -SizeBytes $drivesize
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Resize-VHD], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Vhd.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResizeVhd
```

I think it's a variable type issue, the error says as much, I just have no idea how to fix it.

Edit:

If I write the value of `$drivesize` to the console, I get:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $drivesize
70GB
```

Comment: Yes, the issue was the quotation marks. I removed those and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$drivesize = "70GB" # WRONG: Quoting creates a STRING, but you want a NUMBER
```

use:

```
$drivesize = 70GB  # OK: 70GB is a NUMBER LITERAL, evaluating to 75161927680
```

**To PowerShell, *unquoted numeric tokens with binary-multiplier suffixes* such as `GB` are *numbers***.
Note that **the resulting number's specific integer type *varies***: the smallest signed integer type equal to or larger than `[int]` (`System.Int32`) that can fit the number is used; e.g, `1GB` creates an `[int]`, whereas the above example, `70GB`, creates a `[long]` (`System.Int64`).
Typically, though, you don't have to worry about specific number types in PowerShell, because they are converted to each other on demand.

**Don't store such tokens in *strings***; while PowerShell is generally very flexible when it comes to converting strings that look like numbers to actual numbers, it typically does *not* recognize strings such as `"70GB"` as numbers - see below.

---

**Optional reading: To-number conversion of a *string* containing a numeric token with a suffix such as `GB`**

Perhaps surprisingly, **PowerShell's binary-multiplier suffixes - `kb`, `mb`, `gb`, `tb`, `pb` - only work in number *literals*, and not when (implicitly) converting *from a string*.**

```
PS> 1gb  # produces an [int] whose value is equivalent to 1 * [math]::Pow(2, 30)
1073741824

PS> [int] '1gb' # !! From-string conversion FAILS
Cannot convert value "1gb" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

# Workaround: Simply divide by 1, because PowerShell does
#             recognize the suffix in the context of an *expression*.
PS> '1gb' / 1
1073741824
```

<sup>Tip of the hat to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for providing the workaround.

[*Since fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+*] The surprising discrepancy between recognizing suffixes when performing implicit to-number conversions in *expressions* vs. when *parameter-binding* is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7710).</sup>

The reason that from-string conversion doesn't work is that suffixes are *PowerShell-specific*, whereas conversion of a string to a number type - whether implicitly during parameter binding or explicitly with a cast such as `[int]` - uses *.NET methods* which are unaware of these suffixes.

Therefore, using a string that expresses the same value *without* a multiplier suffix would have worked, for instance:

```
PS> $driveSize = '1073741824'; [UInt64] $driveSize
1073741824
```

Although if you know the value in advance, there is no reason to use a string to begin with, and the use of a number literal avoids the problem:

```
$driveSize = 70GB # creates a [long] (System.Int64) with value 75161927680
```

Note that **PowerShell generally widens numeric types on demand (uses larger-capacity types as needed) and automatically performs signed/unsigned type conversions.**

Therefore, even though `$driveSize` is `System.Int64`-typed based on the statement above, PowerShell automatically converts it to `System.UInt64` (unsigned) when binding to the `SizeBytes` parameter.